# Inserir nomes ao lado das bolhas de um Gráfico Bolha no R e exagerar a diferença entre elas

Tags: r

Boa noite

Estou criando um gráfico bolha no R

Consegui plotar o gráfico e colocar o nome ao lado das bolhas

```
nome<-c("a","b","c","d")

anos<-c(15,8,25,9)
renda<-c(14,5,3,25)
final<-c(30,15,42,12)

tudo<-cbind(nome,anos,renda,final)

tudo<-as.data.frame(tudo)

attach(tudo)
teste<-ggplot(tudo, aes(x=anos, y=renda, size=final)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.6) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(nome)))


teste + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = nome),
                   box.padding   = 0.8, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
  theme_classic()
```

Porém gostaria de saber como faço para que o nome referente a cada bolha não mude de tamanho junto com a bolha, ou seja, todos os nomes das bolhas tenham o mesmo tamanho independente do tamanho da bolha

outra dúvida, na legenda **"final"**, em vez de círculos de escala, aparece um **a**, gostaria de saber como faço para a escala seja representada por **círculos** e não pela letra **a**

Gostaria de saber também se é possível aumentar a diferença de tamanho entre as bolhas, ou seja , exagerar a escala

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta incluir o argumento `size` em `geom_label_repel` para ter o que quer.

Primeiro vou refazer a base, com `data.frame`, o modo mais natural de a criar.

```
nome <- c("a","b","c","d")
anos <- c(15,8,25,9)
renda <- c(14,5,3,25)
final <- c(30,15,42,12)

tudo <- data.frame(nome, anos, renda, final)
```

Agora o gráfico.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

teste <- ggplot(tudo, aes(x=anos, y=renda, size=final)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(nome)), alpha=0.6)

teste + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = nome),
                   size = 5,
                   box.padding   = 0.8, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A segunda pergunta** é a seguinte.

> Gostaria de saber também se é possível aumentar a diferença de tamanho
>   entre as bolhas, ou seja , exagerar a escala

Pode-se somar números cada vez maiores aos valores de `final`, por exemplo somar `10` ao mais pequeno valor, `20` ao segundo maior, etc. Mas `geom_point` acaba por ajustar automaticamente os tamanhos e é muito trabalho para nada.

Este código é uma maneira de fazer isso. Cada valor de `final` é multiplicado por um valor da sequência `1:4`. Mas o gráfico é igual.

```
library(dplyr)

tudo %>%
  mutate(i = order(final),
         final = (seq_along(final)*final[i])[order(i)]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=anos, y=renda, size=final)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(nome)), alpha=0.6) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = nome),
                   size = 5,
                   box.padding   = 0.8, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o problema.